# Typo3 backend user profile image

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I am building a typo3 website with templavoila.

I want to add profile pic option for backend user profiles. Currently there are no options to add profile image in user settings. Is it posiible to add this option to a typo3 website?

Comment: The question is: What do you want to do with that image? Where should it be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an extension for the purpose. Here it is : http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/be_user_profilepic

Git repo: [be_user_profilepic](https://github.com/harishanchu/Typo3-BE-User-Profile-Pic)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You must make an extension that would extend the `be_users` table.

Comment: ok. And what you do with this gravatar pic? Can you post the code?

Comment: function _gravatar($result) {
        $uid = $result['userid'];        
        $query = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery("email","be_users","uid=\"$uid\"");    
        $user = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $email = $user['email'];           
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_free_result($query);
        $s = 50;
        $d = 'mm';
        $r = 'g';       
        $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
        $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
        $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
        return $url;
    }

Comment: Still I need an internal functionality for this.

Comment: Is there any extension available to do this?